# SQL select dummy data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have attempted to create some dummy data from a select statement. I can easily create 1 column with 1 dummy data, or 2 columns with 1 dummy data, but how can I go about making 1 column with 2 dummy data(2 rows)?

```
(No column name)
    dummy1
    dummy2
```

Select statements that are 1 dummy data per column:

```
Select 'dummy'

Select 'dummy1','dummy2'
```

Comment: Reason for down vote? I can't proceed to create better future questions without any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: One way `select * from (values ('dummy'), ('dummy2'), ('dummyN')) T(fname_here)`

Comment: The question per se looks legit maybe people donwvoted because the content. Anyway there are better ways to do it. Create a table (temp, variable or even create a sandbox database) and go full creative with your objects. Inserts can be done a-lot-at-once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to use `UNION` with two select statements:

```
 SELECT 'dummy1' AS [Dummies]
 UNION
 SELECT 'dummy2'
```

This will produce a single column.

```
Dummies
-------
dummy1
dummy2
```

Comment: Martin, very nice answer. This has worked nicely! I'll be sure to reward you when Stack Overflow allows me to. Thank you!

Comment: is it possible to name this column? If I do 'As Dummies' it does nothing.

Comment: The name of the column comes from the first `SELECT`. The second one and subsequent column names are ignored.

Comment: That makes sense. I was appending it from the last one. Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score 15):

Just another option with one or multiple columns

**Single Column**

```
Select *
 From  (values ('Dummy1')
              ,('Dummy2')
       ) A(Dummies)
```

**Returns**

```
Dummies
Dummy1
Dummy2
```

**Multiple Columns**

```
Select *
 From  (values ('Dummy1',1)
              ,('Dummy2',2)
       ) A(Dummies,Value)
```

**Returns**

```
Dummies Value
Dummy1  1
Dummy2  2
```

Comment: And a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to the tsql documentation that describes this.

Comment: is there a way how the single column query works as well for oracle? i have the error message 'invalid table name'

Comment: @and-bri Not an oracle guy.  A single column in SQL Server would be https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=359beaa3cf5987f1b074e620f6da6c8a